# Getting appdelegate value from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, appdelegate

**In Appdelegate.h**
I imported the `playerviewcontroller` in both `Appdelegate.h` and `Appdelegate.m` files.

```
  @class PlayerViewController; 
  @property(nonatomic)float volumeDelegate;
```

**In Appdelegate.m**

```
  @synthesize volumeDelegate;
 - (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
volumeDelegate =1.0
    PlayerViewController *volumeObject=[[PlayerViewController alloc]init];
[volumeObject setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer];
}
```

**In Playerviewcontroller.h**

```
 -(void)setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer;
```

**In Playerviewcontroller.m**

```
@interface PlayerViewController ()
{
AppDelegate *appdelegate;

 }
  -(void)viewDidLoad
  {
  appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  }

  -(void)setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer
  {
[appdelegate.sharedplayer  setVolume:appdelegate.volumeDelegate];
NSLog(@"System Volume in player view:  %f",appdelegate.volumeDelegate);
 }
```

When i run this I get `volumeDelegate` value as Zero as below.

**System Volume in player view:0.000000000**

What is the Mistake I'm making here

Answer (score 35):

You can access to the `AppDelegate` object like below

**Objective-C**

Define it like this:

```
AppDelegate appDelegate;
```

Access it like this:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Usage:

```
- (void)setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer
{
    [appDelegate.sharedplayer  setVolume:appdelegate.volumeDelegate];
    NSLog(@"System Volume in player view:  %f",appDelegate.volumeDelegate);
}
```

---

**Swift:**

Define it like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Usage:

```
func setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer() 
{
    appDelegate.sharedPlayer.setVolume:appDelegate.VolumeDelegate
    print("System Volume in player view: \(appDelegate.volumeDelegate)")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're initializing the `appdelegate` member variable in a `viewDidLoad`, but that method is not called at the moment you call `setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer`!

You're doing

```
PlayerViewController *volumeObject=[[PlayerViewController alloc]init];
[volumeObject setVolumeForAVAudioPlayer];
```

But `alloc init` doesn't make viewController's view to load! `viewDidLoad` is not called at all.